# Join 2 tables using CActiveDataProvider

Tags: php, sql, yii, cactivedataprovider

I've had some problems joining two tables with CActiveDataProvider

The tables are: 
                question(id,description) ,
                questionInFeedback(feedbackId,questionId)

and the relations :

feedback=>

`'questionInFeedbacks' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'QuestionInFeedback','feedbackId'),`

question=>

```
'questionInFeedbacks' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'QuestionInFeedback','questionId'),
```

questionInFeedback=>

```
'feedback' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Feedback', 'feedbackId'),
'question' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Question', 'questionId'),
```

if I could use SQL then i'd use

```
SELECT q.id
FROM questionInFeedback AS qf,Question AS q
WHERE qf.question_id=q.id
```

I need these Questions ID to display in feedback view the question which are related to the feedback.

protected/controllers/feedbackController:

```
$issueDataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Question', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'condition'=>'',
                'params'=>array(':questionId'=>$this->loadModel($id)->id),
```

Thanks for the help :)

EDIT :
Yii is giving me the following error;

"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()", with line 826 being highlighted.

```
{
815         // determine the primary key value
816         if(is_string($this->_pkAlias))  // single key
817         {
818             if(isset($row[$this->_pkAlias]))
819                 $pk=$row[$this->_pkAlias];
820             else    // no matching related objects
821                 return null;
822         }
823         else // is_array, composite key
824         {
825             $pk=array();
826             foreach($this->_pkAlias as $name=>$alias)
827             {
828                 if(isset($row[$alias]))
829                     $pk[$name]=$row[$alias];
830                 else    // no matching related objects
831                     return null;
832             }
833             $pk=serialize($pk);
834         }
835 
836         // retrieve or populate the record according to the primary key value
837         if(isset($this->records[$pk]))
838             $record=$this->records[$pk];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `with` attribute of your criteria to specify the relation:

```
$issueDataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Question', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'condition'=>'t.id = :questionId',
        'params'=>array(':questionId'=>$this->loadModel($id)->id),
         'with' => array('questionInFeedbacks'),
    )
);
```

By the way not sure about your `loadModel` method, but chances are that `$this->loadModel($id)->id` will return the same value as `$id`

So `'params'=>array(':questionId'=>$this->loadModel($id)->id),` could be changed to `'params'=>array(':questionId'=>$id),`

Comment: Hey , thanks for the quick answer. the problem is now something about "alias" - not sure what that means. the error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Could you edit you question with the error? (with the stack trace)

Comment: And what SQL request yii has executed?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. the SQL executed is : 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) 
FROM `question` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `question_in_feedback` `questionInFeedbacks` 

ON (`questionInFeedbacks`.`questionId`=`t`.`id`) 
WHERE (t.id = :questionId)

Comment: Maybe the problem is that one of my tables has a composite key and not a PK?(there is no PK in questionInFeedback)